# How to get the unselected array in NSArray in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I'm making a matching game in iOS using objective-C
there's a 12 set of cards (3 columns and 4 rows) which is an array of `UIButton` connected to `IBOutletCollection`,the problem is when you tap the first card, you can also tap the other cards simultaneously, but the allowable card to tap must be only 2 cards. How can I prevent tapping of cards, if the tapped cards are greater than 1 and less than 2.

Comment: by using `.userInteractionEnabled = YES/NO`

Answer (score 1):

```
//One action for all buttons
-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton*)button
{

//if user select three button at a time, dont do further operations
if (previousButton && currentButton) {
    return;
}

//previous button is the first button
if(previousButton==nil)
{
    previousButton=button;
}
//current button is the second button
else if(currentButton==nil)
{
    currentButton=button;
}
//if button is selected, set button as not selected and vice versa
if([button isSelected]==NO)
{
    [button setSelected:YES];
}
else
{
    [button setSelected:NO];
}
//if user press the same button again and again
if (currentButton==previousButton)
{
    currentButton=nil;
    if([previousButton isSelected]==NO)
    {
        previousButton=nil;
    }
    return;
}    
  else if((currentButton!=previousButton)&&(currentButton!=nil))
{
    //both button tags are same, that means both selected state images are same
    if(previousButton.tag==currentButton.tag)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(delay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
    }
    else
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(delayTwo) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
    }
 } 
 }

-(void)delay
 {
    //[currentButton setHidden:YES];
    //[previousButton setHidden:YES];
  currentButton=nil;
previousButton=nil;
score++;
NSLog(@"Score %d",score);
//the final stage, that means left only two buttons
if(score==6)
{
    //[self endGame];
  }
 } 

-(void)delayTwo
{
   [currentButton setSelected:NO];
   [previousButton setSelected:NO];
  currentButton=nil;
  previousButton=nil;
}
```

In viewDidLoad, assign all button selected & normal state images or title as you required

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are getting at here, but you could try having multiple UITapGestureRecognizer instances. You could have one for 1 tap, one for 2, and one for 3+. That way, you can select the cards for 1 or 2 touches, but ignore it if there are 3 or more.